# Except for COMSOL Multiphysics, what is the dedicated simulation tool (free version) that can simulate arrayed acoustics?

Tags: acoustics, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

Using units and horns, we now have individual replicas. I'm trying to calculate the sound pressure level by arranging hundreds of these in a simulation 1m in front, but when I do it with COMSOL Multiphysics, the calculation amount is wrong. Perhaps there is another software that specializes in simulating arrayed loudspeakers, but what is the best IDE for this?

Comment: I am not aware of a specific package that is dedicated for the calculation of arrays but I believe that, if you know the characteristics of the units (loudspeakers) you could reach a quite decent first approximation by using geometrical acoustics (this actually is the inverse square law in free field) and a free package such as Octave. All you have to do is set the positions of the elements, an array of frequencies of interest, set the polar patterns and calculate for a grid of positions of interest on the 2D/3D space.

Comment: I would think that asking for alternatives is fine for the resource recommendation tag, but asking what the "best IDE" is not well-suited for this site as it's asking for opinions on fancy text editors.